# Why vector<bool>::reference doesn't return reference to bool?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

```
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    void foo(){}
};

template< typename T >
void callIfToggled( bool v1, bool &v2, T & t )
{
    if ( v1 != v2 )
    {
        v2 = v1;
        t.foo();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< bool > v= { false, true, false };

    const bool f = false;
    A a;

    callIfToggled( f, v[0], a );
    callIfToggled( f, v[1], a );
    callIfToggled( f, v[2], a );
}
```

The compilation of the example above produces next error :

```
dk2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
dk2.cpp:29:28: error: no matching function for call to 'callIfToggled(const bool&, std::vector<bool>::reference, A&)'
dk2.cpp:29:28: note: candidate is:
dk2.cpp:13:6: note: template<class T> void callIfToggled(bool, bool&, T&)
```

I compiled using g++ (version 4.6.1) like this :

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -pedantic dk2.cpp
```

The question is why this happens? Is `vector<bool>::reference` not `bool&`? Or is it a compiler's bug?
Or, am I trying something stupid? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, despite its name, `std::vector<bool>` is not a `vector` of `bool`.

Comment: As a workaround, you could use `std::unique_ptr<bool[]>(new bool[3])`...

Comment: Herb Sutter's [When Is a Container Not a Container?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm) is just about this problem.

Comment: Howard Hinnant's article [On vector<bool>](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool) says that it's a good optimization only the name should've been changed to not denote the greater meaning of a standard container.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[Vector is specialized for bool](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)&oldid=767869909#Specialization_for_bool).

It is considered a mistake of the std. Use `vector<char>` instead:

```
template<typename t>
struct foo {
  using type = t;
};
template<>
struct foo<bool> {
  using type = char;
};

template<typename t, typename... p>
using fixed_vector = std::vector<typename foo<t>::type, p...>;
```

---

Occasionally you may need references to a bool contained inside the vector. Unfortunately, using `vector<char>` can only give you references to chars. If you really need `bool&`, check out the [Boost Containers library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/container.html). It has an unspecialized version of `vector<bool>`.

Comment: Nice workaround, and nice demo of the new `using` syntax for aliasing.

Comment: @Nawaz I swear to God that pun was intended.

Answer (score 60):

Your expectations are normal, but the problem is that `std::vector<bool>` has been a kind of experiment by the C++ commitee. It is actually a template specialization that stores the bool values tightly packed in memory: one bit per value.

And since you cannot have a reference to a bit, there's your problem.

Comment: +1. std::vector<bool> only supports a subset of the functionality provided by std::vector. It's ugly since you have to replace bool with a different type (char) to get a working vector.

Comment: An experiment most (if not all) committee members regretted!

Comment: This is a bug by design: when you write the elements of `std::vector<bool>` from multiple CPU threads, you get a race condition and results are incorrect.

Answer (score 26):

`std::vector< bool >` packs its contents so each Boolean value is stored in one bit, eight bits to a byte. This is memory-efficient but computationally intensive, since the processor must perform arithmetic to access the requested bit. And it doesn't work with `bool` reference or pointer semantics, since bits within a byte do not have addresses in the C++ object model.

You can still declare a variable of type `std::vector<bool>::reference` and use it as if it were `bool&`. This allows generic algorithms to be compatible.

```
std::vector< bool > bitvec( 22 );
std::vector< bool >::reference third = bitvec[ 2 ];
third = true; // assign value to referenced bit
```

In C++11, you can work around this using `auto` and the `&&` specifier which automatically selects an lvalue reference bound to the vector element or an rvalue reference bound to a temporary.

```
std::vector< bool > bitvec( 22 );
auto &&third = bitvec[ 2 ]; // obtain a std::vector< bool >::reference
third = true; // assign value to referenced bit
```

Comment: Good answer, especially the mention of `&&`, which is crucial to generic code to let proxy types/iterators ever be useful. Of course, it works equally well in loops: `for (auto &&it: bizarreContainer)`

Answer (score 16):

`std::vector<bool>` is a non conforming container. To optimize space, it packs `bool`s and cannot provide reference.

Use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) instead.

Comment: To get a kind of reference you need to use operator [] (result is dynamic_bitset::reference). There are no iterator though.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning how `dynamic_bitset` is different or better. Of course it can't return a `bool &` either.

Answer (score 5):

Just my 2 cents:

`std::vector<bool>::reference` is a typedef for `struct _Bit_reference` which is defined as

```
typedef unsigned long _Bit_type;

struct _Bit_reference
  {
    _Bit_type * _M_p;
    _Bit_type _M_mask;

    // constructors, operators, etc...

    operator bool() const
    { return !!(*_M_p & _M_mask); }
  };
```

Changing the function like this, it works (well, compiles at least, haven't tested):

```
template< typename T >
void callIfToggled( bool v1, std::vector<bool>::reference v2, T & t )
{
    bool b = v2;  
    if ( v1 != b )
    {
        v2 = v1;
        t.foo();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I changed the condition from (v1 != v2), which wasn't a good idea, to (v1 != b).

Comment: It's not an extension, it's just how GCC implements the vector<bool> specialization. I don't know what standard says about this. You can see it for yourself: std_bvector.h in lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits. (Your directory tree might be different, but probably similar)

Comment: Sure, it works, for this one specific case - further illustrating why `vector<bool>` is an awful misnomer - as it becomes incredibly difficult, tedious, or impossible to use in generic code situations that work for other, _actual_ containers. Still, I think a usable workaround here would be to use `template<typename B, typename T> void callIfToggled(B &&v1, B &&v2, T &&t)` and rely on the conversion operator from `v2` - which I guess is another reason to be thankful for forwarding references. Doesn't excuse the wrong choice of name, though!

Answer (score 1):

Make a structure with a `bool` in it, and make the `vector<>` using that struct type.

Try:

`vector<struct sb>` where `sb` is `struct {boolean b];`

then you can say

`push_back({true})`

do

`typedef struct sbool {bool b;} boolstruct;` and then `vector<boolstruct> bs;`

Comment: You don't need `struct` or `typedef` in C++