# pointing to an object in a std::vector of bool

Tags: c++, c++98

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why vector<bool>::reference doesn’t return reference to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool)

I have a mock class which I am using in my unit tests.

I looks something like:

```
class Mock
{
public:
    ...

    static ReturnType isKeyFunction(bool* _isKey)
    {
        _isKey = &(*isKeyI++);
        ...
    }
    ...
    static std::vector<bool> isKey;
    static std::vector<bool>::iterator isKeyI;
};
```

So the vector is filled with values and the iterator is incremented each time a value is used by the test.

The problem is that the code wont compile and I'm guessing its because std::vector is saved as bits and I can point to a member in it with a bool*.

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vb_reference<_Alloc> *' to 'bool *'
```

How might I solve this?

Comment: Use `std::vector<char>` instead.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is "special".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29#Specialization_for_bool

Comment: Even if `vector<bool>` behaved normally, it doesn't make sense to assign the `_isKey` parameter like you do.

Comment: @interjay Why not? I need to point to a value within the vector.

Comment: Because it will overwrite whatever value is passed to the function for the `_isKey` parameter, so it might as well be a local variable. If your intent is for the caller to see the new value of `_isKey` then this won't work.

Comment: You can use `struct bool_type { bool value; bool_type(bool v) : value(v) { ; } bool * operator & () { return &value; } operator bool & () { return value; } };` and `template< typename T > using B = std::conditional_t< std::is_same< T, bool >{}, bool_type, T >;` to filter the actual type.