# vector<bool>::operator[] misbehavior?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, boolean, auto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why vector<bool>::reference doesn’t return reference to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool)

I used to think that with `std::vector::operator[]` we get **deep** copies of the accessed item, but it seems that it is not always true. At least, with `vector<bool>` the following test code gives a different result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void Test(const T& oldValue, const T& newValue, const char* message)
{
    cout << message << '\n';

    vector<T> v;
    v.push_back(oldValue);
    cout << " before:  v[0] = " << v[0] << '\n';

    // Should be a deep-copy (?)       
    auto x = v[0];   
    x = newValue;

    cout << " after:   v[0] = " << v[0] << '\n';
    cout << "-------------------------------\n";
}

int main()
{
    Test<int>(10, 20, "Testing vector<int>");
    Test<double>(3.14, 6.28, "Testing vector<double>");
    Test<bool>(true, false, "Testing vector<bool>");
}
```

Output (source code compiled with VC10/VS2010 SP1):

> ```
> Testing vector<int>
>  before:  v[0] = 10
>  after:   v[0] = 10
> -------------------------------
> Testing vector<double>
>  before:  v[0] = 3.14
>  after:   v[0] = 3.14
> -------------------------------
> Testing vector<bool>
>  before:  v[0] = 1
>  after:   v[0] = 0
> -------------------------------
> ```

I would have expected that `v[0]` *after* the `x = newValue` assignment would still be equal to its previous value, but this seems not true. 
Why is that? 
Why is `vector<bool>` special?

Comment: Actually `vector<bool>` is quite special by design, see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/

Comment: It is neither a `vector`, nor contains `bool` values.

Comment: This is a very nice example how type deduction can shoot you in the foot and how the solutions to the problem aren't obvious.

Comment: @pmr it's not the type deduction which is at fault here, it's the non-generic behavior of supposedly generic code. they Committee should have renamed `vector<bool>` to `bitvector` (and I believe there were some proposals for that)

Comment: @rhalbersma The code would be working as expected if you would use `T` or `vector<T>::value_type` instead of `auto`. I believe earlier specs required `operator[]` of a container to return something convertible to a `T&`, but that doesn't seem to be the case for C++11 anymore.

Comment: @pmr: I've added the `auto` tag, too.

Comment: @PeterWood: Then better changing its name.

Comment: See also http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector<bool>::operator[]` neither yields a `bool` nor a reference to a `bool`. It just returns a little **proxy object** that acts like a reference. This is because there are no references to single bits and `vector<bool>` actually stores the `bool`s in a compressed way. So by using `auto` you just created a copy of that reference-like object. The problem is that C++ does not know that this object acts as a reference. You have to force the "decay to a value" here by replacing `auto` with `T`.

Comment: I've done some edits to this post to just format some text like "auto" as code.

Answer (score 21):

`vector<bool>` is a hideous abomination and special. The Committee specialized it to pack bits, therefore it does not support proper reference semantics, as you cannot refer to a bit, this means that it has a non-conforming interface and does not actually qualify as a Standard Container. The solution that most people use is simply to never, ever, use `vector<bool>`.

Comment: As noted in [this blog post](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool) (pointed by @JonathanWakely), having an array of bits data structure can be good. Probably the choice of the name `vector<bool>` is not good, if the "public interface" is kind of different than usual `vector<T>`.

Comment: It's very bad to specialize a container like this. There should be `dynamic_bitset`.

Comment: @DeadMG there is, in Boost.

Comment: `vector<char>` or similar is a decent alternative

Comment: I would prefer `deque<bool>`, meets all I need - also supports [], dynamic, compatible with old C++ compiler, a real STL container

Answer (score 4):

`operator[]` returns a `T&` for every value of `T` except for `bool`, where it gives a reference proxy. See this [old column](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm) by Herb Sutter on why using `vector<bool>` in generic code is bad idea (and why it is not even a container). There is also a special Item about it in Effective STL by Scott Meyers, and tons of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool?lq=1) on it here at SO.