# How to list the word with the highest score

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find out how to list the word with the highest score, based on this function to calculate a score, the words come from an array of words, or so. How can I tackle this?

Comment: _tackle what_ ? Also why `else {Letter = '-'; ...}` ?

Comment: Scrabble: Hmm, what about those pesky blank tiles?  Suggest changing `else {` into `else if (Letter != ' ') {`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you just need the word with *highest* score, there is no need to keep track of scores for *all* candidate words. Keeping track of the *best* one is enough.

```
string best_word;
int best_score = 0;
for (auto word &: all_the_words) {
    int cur_score = ScrabbleScore(word);
    if (cur_score > best_score) {
        best_word = word;
        best_score = cur_score;
    }
}
// Now you have best_word and best_score.
```

**Edit**: Extend to take care of all words with the same best score.

```
vector<string> best_words;
int best_score = 0;
for (auto word &: all_the_words) {
    int cur_score = ScrabbleScore(word);
    if (cur_score > best_score) {
        best_words.clear();
        best_words.push_back(word);
        best_score = cur_score;
    } else if (cur_score == best_score) {
        best_words.push_back(word);
    }
}
// Now you have best_words and best_score.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your word strings in a `std::vector<std::string>`, and call `std::sort()` algorithm on that vector, specifying a **custom comparison function** to sort the words by their "score".

See the following sample code for details:

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::sort
#include <exception>    // for std::exception
#include <iostream>     // for std::cout
#include <stdexcept>    // for std::runtime_error
#include <string>       // for std::string
#include <vector>       // for std::vector
using namespace std;

// NOTE #1: Since this function is *observing* the "word" parameter,
// pass it by const reference (const string & word).
int ScrabbleScore(const string & word) {
    int score = 0;
    static const char scoreTable[26] = { 
        1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 
        5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 
    };

    for (auto letter : word) {
        // if alphabet word
        if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
            score += scoreTable[letter - 'a'];
        } else {
            // NOTE #2: Throw an exception when an invalid
            // letter is found.
            throw runtime_error("Invalid letter in word.");
        }
    }   
    return score;
}

int main() {
    // Some test words
    vector<string> words = {
        "hi", "hello", "world", "ciao",
        "integer", "sum", "sort", "words"
    };

    // Sort vector by ScrabbleScore (descending order)
    sort(words.begin(), words.end(), 
        [](const string& lhs, const string& rhs) {
            return ScrabbleScore(lhs) > ScrabbleScore(rhs);
        }
    );

    // Print result
    cout << "<word> (<score>)" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    for (const auto & w : words) {
        cout << w << " (" << ScrabbleScore(w) << ")" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> <word> (<score>)
> ------------------
> world (9)
> words (9)
> hello (8)
> integer (8)
> ciao (6)
> hi (5)
> sum (5)
> sort (4)
> ```

Comment: +1 for `**static const** char scoreTable[26]`.

Comment: Hey thanks for this the code, I'm trying to understand how it works the only part of the code which I don't understand is `for (const auto & w : words)` where can I read up on this?

Comment: Sorting a list to find the maximum is very inefficient.

Comment: @Hayde: the above `for` is a C++11 _"for each"_ . It means: `for (const string & w : words)` (i.e. _"for each string in words vector"_). I used `const &` instead of just `string` since the for loop is _observing_ the items, so I use `const` reference; you can find more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15927033/1629821).

Comment: @Dukeling: I agree; if just the maximum is required, there are better ways. I thought more of a general vector "custom sorting" solution, listing also the scores of the other ("non-maximum score") words.