# Why does CArray crash when using RemovAll() in this instance?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, mfc

I can't seem to figure out a way to prevent this block of code from crashing:

```
CArray<Mat, Mat> ary;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Mat rawmat(5,5,CV_8U);
    ary.Add(rawmat);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ary.GetAt(i).release();
}
ary.FreeExtra();
ary.RemoveAll();
```

I've also tried using a reference via:

```
CArray<Mat, Mat&> ary;
```

Same issue. This doesn't occur with a CList, but I'd rather use a CArray for random iteration purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CArray` is an *old* MFC container class, with an old design.

I'd recommend using a *more modern* approach, with STL containers, like **`std::vector`** (instead of `CArray`).

You can use `std::vector::push_back()` to add new items to it.
And if you want to clear all vector's content, you can call its `clear()` method.

```
#include <vector>  // for using std::vector

....

// Create an empty std::vector
std::vector<Mat> arrayOfMats;

// Use vector::push_back() to add new items to it
Mat someMat(...);
arrayOfMats.push_back(someMat);
```

You can use `std::vector::size()` to get the number of items stored in the vector.

And you can iterate through the vector content using an integer index upper-bounded to the vector's size (similar to what you did with `CArray`), or just using the [new C++11's range-for loop syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15927037/1629821).

---

Note that you can still use other MFC classes for other parts of your applications, e.g. for the GUI, for Windows API interaction, etc.
STL's container classes like `std::vector` can just be used in the "business logic", in the "core" of your application code.

---

Going deeper into your problem, it seems that the `Mat` class you used in your code (probably from OpenCV, considering one of your question tag...) is *not* "trivially copyable" using `memcpy` (or its safer `memcpy_s` version), so it is not a good candidate for simple use with `CArray`, as you can read in [the `CArray` MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct.aspx) (**emphasis mine**):

> **Most methods that resize a `CArray` object or add elements to it use `memcpy_s` to move elements. This is a problem because `memcpy_s` is
>   not compatible with any objects that require the constructor to be
>   called.** If the items in the `CArray` are not compatible with
>   `memcpy_s`, you must create a new `CArray` of the appropriate size.
>   You must then use `CArray::Copy` and `CArray::SetAt` to populate the
>   new array because those methods use an assignment operator instead of
>   `memcpy_s`.

Instead, note how this kind of problem does *not* occur with `std::vector`, which plays nice with non-trivially-copyable classes.