# c++ vector for each loop doesn't iterate through references?

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, reference, pass-by-reference

yesterday I spent almost an our while debugging this thing and since then I can't stop thinking about it.C

I tried to implement a 2D matrix with string indexes...

```
class CSqrMatrix(){
  ....
  void insert(string str){
     bool b = map.insert(str,m_size).second;
     if (b){
         m_size++;
         vector<int> ve;
         for (int i = 0; i < m_vect.size(); i++) 
             ve.push_back(m_default);
         m_vect.push_back(ve);
         for (auto v : m_vect)
             v.push_back(m_default);
     }
  ...
map<string,int> map;
vector < vector<int> > m_vect;
int m_default;
int m_size;
};
```

after some insertions, when I tried to reach an element like

```
m_vect[0][0] = 8;
```

I got an invalid write and segfault... and the value of `m_vect[0].size()` was 0;
I tried everything, when finally I changed the for each loop to a normal one like

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_vect.size(); i++){
     m_vect[i].push_back(m_default);
```

the program worked well...

So does that mean, that `v` ins't a referecne, but a new copy of the element?

Thanks
(there might be typos in the code, I wrote it on the phone...)

Comment: Yes that's right. Try `for (auto& v : m_vect)` if you want a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code:

```
for (auto v : m_vect)
    v.push_back(m_default);
```

is equivalent to following (*see C++ standard [stmt.ranged]*):

```
{
    auto && __range = (m_vect);
    for (auto __begin = __range.begin(), __end = __range.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin)
    {
        auto v = *__begin;      // <-- new copy in each iteration
        v.push_back(m_default); // add item to the copy
                                // the copy goes out of scope
    }
}
```

So, yes, `v` ins't a referecne, but a new copy in each iteration?

What you want is:

```
for (auto& v : m_vect)
    v.push_back(m_default);
```

That is equivalent to:

```
{
    auto && __range = (m_vect);
    for (auto __begin = __range.begin(), __end = __range.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin)
    {
        auto& v = *__begin; // <-- new reference in each iteration
        v.push_back(m_default);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> for (auto v : m_vect)
>     v.push_back(m_default);
> ```

In the above form, the range-for loop iterates using **copies** (`v`) of the items stored in `m_vect`.

If you want to operate directly on **references** to the items in `m_vect`, you should be explicit about that, using **`auto&`**:

```
// v references items in m_vect
for (auto& v : m_vect) {
    v.push_back(m_default);
}
```

You may find [this StackOverflow answer on using C++11 range-for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15927037/1629821) interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes `v` is indeed a copy. You should do it like this:

```
for (auto& v : m_vect){
   v.push_back(m_default);
}
```

And keep in mind that `std::vector` copy is a deep copy for the container and for all items which is really an expensive operation. So if you want to pass through a vector of vectors (`std::vector<std::vector<T>>`) even without editing, you should pass by ref (with `const` if you do not want editing):

```
for(/*const*/ auto& v:vectors){
   //...
}
```