# Iterate using auto&& in for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

In clion 2017.1 when I choose live template for iterating a range (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> iter), then I get the following code:

```
for (auto &&item : __) {

}
```

Is it really a good idea to use forwading reference as iteration object? If its used as a live template then maybe it is becoming a standard?

Comment: @nwp Pretty sure that's not an r-value reference.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for

Comment: @nwp it is a forwarding reference. `auto` follows the rules of template argument deduction (plus one or two gizmos for `initializer_list`s).

Comment: Whether or not it's always the right choice is debatable, but it's a choice that always works. So you *can* use it per default. (Reposted due to typo which changed the meaning.)

Comment: @Baum : Considering that the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15927037/15416) answers this question as well, I'd even call it a duplicate. Any objections to closing this?