# Compare inline function in std::sort()

Tags: c++, sorting

I copied this code online. it is about sorting big numbers:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<string> a(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
}
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), 
    [](const string &left, const string &right)
{
    if (left.size() != right.size()) 
    {
        return left.size() < right.size();
    } 
    else 
    {
        return left < right;
    }
});
for (const string &s : a) {
    cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Can somebody explain these lines by words:

```
[](const string &left, const string &right)
```

and

```
for (const string &s : a)
```

I have never encountered the  library as well as a for loop like the code used.
Thanks!

Comment: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11/7627218#7627218), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) at least (or [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) or [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17)), e.g. some good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) (any standard older than C++11 is obsolete, and C++11 has evolved a lot since its predecessors, so you should almost consider C++11 as a new programming language). Look also some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site.

`[](const string &left, const string &right)` starts a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), that is an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) implemented as a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Then you have a [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop: `for (const string &s : a)` which could even be `for (const auto& s: a)` or in your case `for (auto s: a)` because the [`auto` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) brings a limited form of [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).

Read also [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) to improve your views on programming (it is not about C++, but an excellent and freely downloadable introduction to programming).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's just because I don't know the keyword "lambda expression" to google, I have to seek for help here.

Comment: Take time to read SICP. It will improve your C++ coding style