# Iterate in C++ like in python

Tags: python, c++, loops

I would like to iterate in C++ over a set of values. In python, it looks like

```
for v in [v1, v2, v3]:
    do_something()
```

What is the correct way to do it in C++?

Comment: If you are able to use C++11 or higher, you can use [range for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: I do not see why people are closing this question, it is a valid question.

Comment: You should also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (const auto& v : {v1, v2, v3}) { do_something(); }
```

Would be equivalent (except for the fact that the elements in the initializer list will conceptually be *copied* - even if the optimizer elides those copies - so they will need to be copyable).

Comment: Unfortunately, not entirely - those variables are going to be copied into initializer list (at least semantically), so copy constructor has to be available.

Comment: @SergeyA Fair point. It's the closest equivalent *I* could think of. If you have a closer one, please post an answer and I'll upvote that and delete this one.

Comment: I do not know of any closer one which would be that concise, and I have a feeling it will not necessarily matter for OP, I just think you might want to make a note of that in your answer.

Comment: I think I'm not using C++11: "range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11"

Comment: @heracho then I would advise getting up-to-date with the latest C++ version (currently C++17) :-) You *can* do the same thing in C++98, it just won't be nearly as concise, nor as readable.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the auto keyword and a range based for loop

```
 std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

 for (auto const& e:v){
      // here e is value from v
 }
```

more info: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Note that `auto`, `auto&`, `const auto &` and `auto&&` have different meanings and it's not clear which would be appropriate here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux right thats why i included more documentation

Answer (score 1):

What about  **std::apply**  C++17 function:

```
std::apply([](auto&& v){ do_something_over_v();}, std::tie(v1,v2,v3) ) ;
```

- Needn't copy of v1, v2, v3 elements, just took reference of them.
- Needn't require to identity type of v1, v2, v3.

If you don't have C++17, just copy implementation from reference -) , worked for C++14 mode, as I know.

[reference to std::apply](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)