# DIfference of Auto in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, auto

I wanted to know the difference between :

```
for(auto i : vector ){
     cout << i << " ";
}
```

And :

```
for( auto &i : vector){
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

It would be helpful if someone points out the difference between these two 
Thanks ! :)

Comment: One uses values (so makes copies), other one uses references. Depending on the contents of `vector` one might be better than the other in certain cases.

Comment: Also [What is the correct way of using C++11's range-based for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for)

Comment: In generic code `auto&&` may be useful.