# Ranged based for loop for vector of booleans

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, boolean

`std::vector<bool>` uses proxy iterators.

So the following code will not compile (code taken from the accepted answer in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for) ):

```
vector<bool> v = {true, false, false, true};
for (auto& x : v)
    x = !x;
```

In the related question, the accepted answer states that to modify the components of the vector in place, we must use

```
for (auto&& x : v)
    x = !x;
```

But if I simply do:

```
for (auto x : v)
    x = !x;
```

This produces identical results. So is the `&&` not needed?

Further why does the following 2 codes not modify the components?

```
for (bool &&x : v)
    x = !x;
```

and

```
for (bool x : v)
    x = !x;
```

Comment: Inspecting the *type* of  `x` with the second and third snippets, as compared to the final two, is probably going to be illuminating.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the `for` loop and you will see that using `auto` does not result in `x` having a `bool` type.

Comment: Guys, read the first line of the question.

Comment: I think I misunderstood how proxy iterators work. That answers my last question. I'm still confused on why `auto &&` and `auto` generates the same behavior? In all the related questions I've seen, the answers use `auto &&`.

Comment: The whole point of auto&& is that it works both for vector<bool> and vector<int>. You could also not use auto at all and be explicit about the type.

Comment: @MarcGlisse just `auto` works also for both int and bool.

Comment: @n314159 but will just `auto` allow you to modify the values of the vector in your loop? Yes for bool, no for int. I believe that's why Marc is saying use `auto&&` whenever you want to change things. It's just one less thing to worry about.

Comment: Ah, yes, sry I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: The proxy object knows how to read and write the single bits, regardless of how you keep it. Converting the proxy object to `bool` loses that information.

---

```
for (auto&& x : v)
    x = !x;
```

and

```
for (auto x : v)
    x = !x;
```

have the same behavior because in each case the proxy object (`std::vector<bool>::reference`) obtained from dereferencing a `std::vector<bool>::iterator` is stored in `x`. Whether the proxy object is stored by value or reference doesn't matter - its behavior of modifying the proxied bit is the same.

In

```
for (bool &&x : v)
    x = !x;
```

and

```
for (bool x : v)
    x = !x;
```

the proxy object is implicitly converted to a `bool`. This necessarily loses the information needed (and thus the capability) to affect the compressed bit.

Note that these are all implementation-defined. Your implementation is allowed to forego the space optimization too, in which case the behavior you see could be different. Only `auto&&` works in every case.

Comment: I would add that the reason for using `auto&&` over `auto` is that it is more generic. If you replaced the `vector<bool>` with a vector of heavy objects, `auto` would make copies, while `auto&&` would not. (This is also the case for the current code, as you said, but here it doesn't matter performancewise)

Comment: @n314159 I did not add that because I would strongly advise against combining `std::vector<bool>` and generic code. Well, generic in the `std::vector<T>` sense. It's just a giant minefield.

Comment: I agree, that one should not do that (personally, I would just stay far away from `std::vector<bool>` if possible). I just think OP wonders, why nearly all code in this context uses `auto&&` instead of `auto`. That's why I find it somewhat relevant.