# C++ beginner, Access Violation when trying to print out values

Tags: c++, for-loop, access-violation

I've recently started learning c++ after 5 years with python and am struggling quite a bit when it comes to loops. the whole for(;;) business.

in python i was used to:

```
for x in y:
    print(x)

> x
> y
> z
```

however in c++ i seem to need two semi-colons like

```
for(;;)
```

what i would like to do is print the paths of my directories given in the below code. Thank you for your time!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

using namespace std;


HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);




// -- main
int main(void) {
    // -- console
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);
    
    // -- paths
    string ScanDir[2] = {"C:/Users/Stephen/Downloads/", "C:/Users/Stephen/Documents/"};
    
    // -- loops
    for (int i = 0; i < ScanDir->length(); ++i) {
        string ss = ScanDir[i];
        cout << ss.c_str() << "\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

here is the error:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnaRr.jpg)

Comment: `ScanDir->length();` -- What did you expect this to do?  Also don't use `Python` or any other computer language as a model in writing C++ code.  C++ is a different language with different rules, different syntax, different idioms.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ arrays are not objects in the OOP sense and do not have methods. They are just a dumb block of memory.

```
ScanDir->length()
```

is not getting the length of the array. Instread `ScanDir` is [decaying to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) to the first `string` in the array and `length` is being called on this `string`. As a result

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScanDir->length(); ++i)
```

iterates length of the first `string` times, not length of the array, and shoots off the end of the array and into the unknown. This invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which in this case lead to a crash.

The smart thing to do is use a [Range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for (const auto & dir: ScanDir) {
    cout << dir.c_str() << "\n";
}
```

which figures out the dimensions for you. Some additional reading on the `const auto &` bit: [What is the correct way of using C++11's range-based for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for)

You can also use

```
for (int i = 0; i < std::size(ScanDir); ++i)
```

if compiling to C++ 17 or better or replace the [magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) 2 in

```
string ScanDir[2] = {"C:/Users/Stephen/Downloads/", "C:/Users/Stephen/Documents/"};
```

with a constant that can be used wherever the size of the array is required.

Another alternative is replace the array with a smarter container like [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
std::array<std::string, 2> ScanDir = {"C:/Users/Stephen/Downloads/", "C:/Users/Stephen/Documents/"};
```

which has a `size` method.

Answer (score 0):

`ScanDir->length()` is the length of your strings which is notably greater than 2. You can either use 2 as upper loop boundary or `sizeof(ScanDir) / sizeof(ScanDir[0])`, or type the loop itself as `for(auto const &ss: ScanDir) count << ss.c_str() << '\n';`.