# auto & vs auto &&: Which one should we use in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, move, auto

I've read this link: [What is the correct way of using C++11's range-based for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927033/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-c11s-range-based-for), I've known why we use `auto &&` to loop a `vector<bool>`. But I still have one more question about `auto &` and `auto &&`.

```
class Test {};
vector<Test> vec = {Test{}, Test{}, Test{}};
vector<Test> vec2;
// case 1
for (auto &element : vec) {
    vec2.emplace_back(element);
}
// case 2
for (auto &element : vec) {
    vec2.emplace_back(std::move(element));
}
// case 3
for (auto &&element : vec) {
    vec2.emplace_back(element);
}
// case 4
for (auto &&element : vec) {
    vec2.emplace_back(std::move(element));
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to insert the objects from the `vec` into the `vec2` with the method **move constructor** of the class `Test`.

I don't know which case I should use, which case is better, which cases are wrong.

Ofc, you might say that we can simply do `vec2 = std::move(vec);`, this is correct but I want to know how to move-construct each element in a for loop, instead of move-construct the container.

Comment: If you want to move, you can start by throwing away case 1 and 3. The other two are equivalent.

Comment: I vote Case 5, which is Case 4 except it uses `std::forward` and am making it a comment instead of an answer because I don't want to do the research right now. The type of `it` may be r-value reference, but `it` is itself an l-value, so it must be moved. What I'm unsure of is if `it` is a universal reference or not. I know `auto` type deduction is largely the same as regular template deduction, but I can't remember if this is an edge case or not. And that's all after I consider if forwarding is what I want or not. I'm starting to think not, and my vote moves back to Case 4 if that's the case.

Comment: Case 1 and Case 3 are the same, Case 2 and Case 4 are the same here.

Comment: @Jarod42  You are right, let me rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a specific reason to write your own loop, I'd say none of the above. Instead, I'd use:

```cpp
std::move(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2));
```

At least by my reading, this makes it fairly apparent both:

1. what you're trying to accomplish, and
2. that you're really doing what you want to.

Comment: I have questions about this code. The first is how this call to `std:::move` is supposed to work, and how it could possibly push anything back on `vec2` given that `std::vector::back()` is just for accessing the last element. Is there some voodoo I'm missing out on?

Comment: @sweenish: Oops--typed the wrong thing there.

Comment: I still don't follow. If this were `std::copy()`, it'd be closer, you'd just need a `std::back_inserter(vec2)` and not `vec2.end()`. But `std::move()` looks nothing like `std::copy()`

Comment: @sweenish: There are two entirely different things called `std::copy`. The one you see a lot is basically just a cast to rvalue reference in disguise. But the other is a whole like like `std::copy`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move

Comment: Okay, cool. I did not know this version of `std::move()` existed. But the example on that page does show that you'd still want `std::back_inserter(vec2)` and not `vec2.end()`.

Comment: @sweenish: Yeah--I should probably know to stop and think for at least a second before typing things in, but apparently I never quite learn. At least my thesis was fairly quickly proven correct: the problem was almost immediately obvious to somebody looking at it who was actually thinking clearly. :-)