# How to find indices in an std::vector<bool> which are true?

Tags: c++

I have say the following bool vector

`v = [false ,true, false ,false ,true, false ,false ,true]`

I want another vector which contains the indices of v for which the elements are true.

I have the following code:

```
std::vector<int> nds; //contains the indices
for (const auto &elem : v)
{
    auto idx = &elem - &v[0];
    if (elem)
    {
        nds.push_back(idx);
    }
}
```

The above seems to work on my MacBook but it is causing the following error on Linux.

```
src/file.cpp:76:25: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
                         auto idx = &elem - &v[0];
                                                ^
```

Is there a better way to find the indices?

P.S. This is just a snippet of some larger code.

Comment: Closely related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool

Comment: And on the whole, I recommend reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool

Comment: If you want the indices, loop over the indices. The range loop is useful when you don't care about what they are.

Comment: the storage for a boolean in a vector of bools is (often) just a bit, which is not addressable, so it (may) return a proxy to it (not the actual storage), which is a temporary object.  I recommend just not using vector<bool> ever - even if all you do is wrap a bool in a struct and make a vector<mybool>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there a better way to find the indices?

Use a classical for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
  if (v[i]) nds.push_back(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) library, you can use a functional programming style approach to chain the lazy [`views::enumerate`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1enumerate__fn.html) iterator with the lazy  [`views::filter`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1filter__fn.html) and [`views::transform`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1filter__fn.html) view transformations to construct an `std::vector<int>` of the `true`-valued (original) indices:

```
const auto nds = v | views::enumerate 
   | views::filter([](auto p) { return p.second; }) 
   | views::transform([](auto p) { return p.first; }) 
   | to<std::vector<int>>;
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/EYErr7).

---

Alternatively, replacing the `views::transform` with [`views::keys`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1keys__fn.html):

```
const auto nds = v | views::enumerate 
    | views::filter([](auto p){ return p.second; })
    | views::keys
    | to<std::vector<int>>;
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/2_vZ3o).